# Update user input as they type it

Tags: java, android, xml

This problem is related a basic app that utilizes email intent.

The UI of the app displays 4 inputs:

1. Email Address
2. Subject
3. Name
4. Messages
5. Button

The message is of a `textMultiLine` input type.

The message has a default text that says: `"Hello CustomerName (This is a dynamic variable that would update as the user types their name in input number 3), could you please review our app..."`

What I am trying to do is to update in real-time the `CustomerName` to the actual customer name as they type it in input number `3` (Name).

Source:

```
package com.example.apit.testemailintent;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText receiver, sub, mesg;
    EditText customerName;
    Button btn;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        receiver = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
        sub = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.subject);
        customerName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
        mesg = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.message);
        btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submitButton);

        addListenerOnButton1();

    }

    public void addListenerOnButton1() {
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                String Sendto = receiver.getText().toString();
                String subject = sub.getText().toString();
                String cusName = customerName.getText().toString();
                String mesgs = "Hello " + cusName + ", could you please review our app...?";


                Intent email = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{Sendto});
                email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
                email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, mesgs);

                email.setType("message/rfc822");
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(email, "Please Choose an Email Client"));

            }
        });

    }

}
```

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
nameEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

   @Override
   public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}

   @Override
   public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
     int count, int after) {
   }

   @Override
   public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,int before, int count) {
      messageEditText.setText("Hello " + s + " could you please review our app")
   }
  });
```

Comment: If I implement this method, how can I refer the message variable in email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, mesgs); ?

Comment: use String to store onTextChanged charSequence and use this String